# make a function that take an integer and reduces it down to an odd number

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on my final for a class I'm taking(Python 3) im stuck at this part.

he gave us a file with numbers inside of it. we opened it and add those numbers to a list.

"Create a function called makeOdd() that returns an integer value.  This function should take in any integer and reduce it down to an odd number by dividing it in half until it becomes an odd number.
       o For example 10 would be cut in half to 5. 
       o 9 is already odd, so it would stay 9. 
       o But 12 would be cut in half to 6, and then cut in half again to 3. 
       o While 16 would be cut to 8 which gets cut to 4 which gets cut to 2 which                gets cut to 1.
 Apply this function to every number in the array. "

I have tried to search the internet but i have not clue where to even begin with this one. any help would be nice.

Here my whole final so far:

```
#imports needed to run this code. 
from Final_Functions import *


#Defines empty list
myList = []
sumthing = 0
sortList = []
oddList = []
count = 0

#Starts the Final Project with my name,class, and quarter
intro()
print("***************************************************************",'\n')

#Opens the data file and reads it then places the intrager into a list we can use later.
with open('FinalData.Data', 'r') as f:
    myList = [line.strip() for line in f]
print("File Read Complete",'\n')



#Finds the Sum and Adverage of this list from FinalData.Data
print("*******************sum and avg*********************************")
for oneLine in myList:
    tempNum = int(oneLine)
    sumthing = sumthing + tempNum
avg = sumthing /1111
print("The Sum of the List is:",sumthing)
print("The Adverage of the List is:",avg,'\n')
print("***************************************************************",'\n')


#finds and prints off the first Ten and the last ten numbers in the list
firstTen(myList)
lastTen(myList)
print("***************************************************************",'\n')


#Lest sort the list then find the first and last ten numbers in this list
sortList = myList
sortList.sort()
firstTen(sortList)
lastTen(sortList)
print("****************************************************************",'\n')
```

Language:Python 3

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please show us your effort.

Comment: "i have not clue where to even begin" - really? don't know how to open a file, dont know how to read numbers, don't know how to divide by two, don't know how to check whether a number is odd or even, none of that?

Comment: i have doone the first half of the fianl just the part i have posted i dont know how to do. I have only gotten my list to drop all even numbers.                              for i in myList:
    if count % 2 == 1:
        oddList.append(i)
    count += 1

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give you the answer outright, so I'm going to talk you through the process and let you generate your own code.

You can't solve this problem in a single step. You need to divide repeatedly and check the value every time to see if it's odd.

Broadly speaking, when you need to repeat a process there are two ways to proceed; looping and recursion. (Ok, there are lots, but those are the most common)

When looping, you'd check if the current number `x` is odd. If not, halve it and check again. Once the loop has completed, `x` will be your result.

If using recursion, have a function that takes `x`. If it's odd, simply return `x`, otherwise call the function again, passing in `x/2`.

Either of those methods will solve your problem and both are fundamental concepts.

Comment: `for num in myList:
    oddTemp = int(num)
    oddTemp = oddTemp / a
    oddList.append(oddTemp)
    print(oddTemp)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that snippet of code is meant to be? Is that what you've understood my answer to be? Or what you currently have? or ??? That code loops through your list of inputs, but you need a second loop (for each input) to divide repeatedly (or calculate `a` if you prefer to think of it that way). Try reading this to get you started: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm It's in Python2 so the `print` syntax is slightly different, but the core functionality is identical

Answer (score 0):

adding to what @Basic said, never do `import *` is a bad practice and is a potential source of problem later on...

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are still confuse in this simple matter, you want to given a number X reduce it to a odd number by dividing it by 2, right? then ask yourself how I do this by hand? the answer is what @Basic said you first ask "X is a even number?" if the answer is No then I and done reducing this number, but if the answer is Yes then the next step dividing it by 2 and save the result in X, then repeat this process until you get to the desire result. Hint: use a `while`

to answer your question about

```
for num in myList:
    if num != 0:
        num = float(num)
        num / 2
```

the problem here is that you don't save the result of the division, to do that is as simple as this

```
for num in myList:
    if num != 0:
        num = float(num)
        num = num / 2
```